# How to parse copy of variable instead of pointer in go?

Tags: go, goquery

In below code snippet I parse http response body 'b' to func parseGoQuery and it is ok first time, but when I do it second time in main() it shows me that response 'b' is 0 inside func parseGoQuery. I think I pass copy of variable 'b' , not pointer, I am confused...please advice

```
resp, _ := client.Get(URL)
    b :=resp.Body

    defer b.Close() // close Body when the function returns
        parseGoQuery("tag1", b)  //b is not 0 as expected, good
    parseGoQuery("tag2", b)  //b is 0 !!!???
```

Here is func parseGoQuery

```
func parseGoQuery(tag string, b io.Reader) {
    fmt.Println(tag,b)
//skipped
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Response.body is of type io.Readcloser.
So once you read from the body, it will get closed and further attempts to read from it will give a zero value.
You can only read from the body once.

So, Store the data you have read from body in a variable and pass that variable to that function.

Comment: But this is what I am doing , storing response from body in variable 'b' and passing 'b' to func

Comment: @irom No, this is _absolutely_ not what your are doing when you write `b :=  resp.Body`: This line declares b to be "the same as" resp.Body", nothing else. You are not reading from the body nor are you making a "deep" copy. You simply cannot read from resp.Body more than once, no matter what you try to do. It does not matter whether you read from b or from resp.Body. Take the Tour of Go for details.